# Why does NSolve not solve my system of simultaneous equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I can not get my code to work.

I think my problem is rudimentary, but please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
TH = 3;
S = 6;
μe = 30;
μg = 30;
λe = 300;
m = Array[Subscript[p, #1, #2] &, {S + 1, TH + 1}, {0, 0}]
NSolve[{
 For[j = 0, j < TH, j++,
  For[i = 0, i < S, i++,
   If[j == 0 && i == TH, μe*Subscript[p, i, j] == λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
   If[j == 0 && TH < i && i < S, (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]];
   If[j == 0 && i == TH, (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
   If[j == S - 1 && S - TH <= i && i < S, (μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
   If[j == TH - 1 && 0 < i && i < TH, (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j - 1] + μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]];
   If[j == TH && i == 0, λe*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j - 1] + μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j]];
   If[j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH, (λe + μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe* Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j], (λe + μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]]
  ]
 ]
}, {m}]
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Table` instead of `For`. Otherwise, you won't get a list of equations since `For` has `Null` as return value. You will also need `Flatten` to transform arrays of equations and variables into list of depth 1.

Comment: How to understand this combination `TH = 3; S = 6; For[j = 0, j < TH ...If[j == S - 1 && `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax issues.

`NSolve` wants two arguments, the 1st being a simple list of equations and the 2nd being a simple list of variables.

Your `NSolve` expression essentially boils down to

```
NSolve[{Null}, {<4 x 7 array of variables>}]
```

because `For` ***always*** returns `Null` and because `m` is not a sequence of variables.

The fix lies in using `Table` to define the equations and applying `Flatten` to both the equation array and the variable array to get simple lists. I will also use `Solve` because there is no inexact quantities in the equations.

```
m = Array[Subscript[p, #1, #2] &, {S + 1, TH + 1}, {0, 0}] // Flatten;
eqns = 
  Table[
    If[j == 0 && i == TH, 
      μe*Subscript[p, i, j] == λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
    If[j == 0 && TH < i && i < S, 
      (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]];
    If[j == 0 && i == TH, 
      (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
    If[j == S - 1 && S - TH <= i && i < S, 
      (μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j]];
    If[j == TH - 1 && 0 < i && i < TH, (λe + μe)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j - 1] + μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]];
    If[j == TH && i == 0, 
      λe*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j - 1] + μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j]];
    If[j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH, 
      (λe + μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j], 
      (λe + μe + μg)*Subscript[p, i, j] == μe*Subscript[p, i + 1, j] + λe*Subscript[p, i - 1, j] + μg*Subscript[p, i, j + 1]],
    {j, 0, TH - 1}, {i, 0, S - 1}] // Flatten
Solve[eqns, m]
```

This gives

[image: result]

which shows your system is under determined, but which is an improvement over your attempt although it may not be what you expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will refer to you.

Comment: @KentaKawai. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.